# Why is the public key in `.near-credentials` keypairs seemingly irrelevant?

Tags: nearprotocol

Let's say I create an account `foo.near` on NEAR with a single full access public key `ed25519:publiccc` which is matched to a private key `ed25519:secrettt` and stored locally in the `.near-credentials/mainnet/foo.near.json` file.

I can now send myself 1 NEAR using `near send foo.near foo.near 1` to verify the keys work.  If I modify the private key in that keypair at all, the send fails. Good.

Then I replace the public key in that keypair with a nonsense string like `ed25519:giggle`.

I can still send myself 1 NEAR using the same command.  Why?

It appears the public key is totally irrelevant in this keypair.  You can use a nonsense string or a public key that's supposed to have limited access only and the private key gives full access to transfer funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! I had to do some digging. So let's start with what the CLI is doing behind the scenes. The code is found [here](https://github.com/near/near-cli/blob/master/index.js#L258-L265):

```js
exports.sendMoney = async function (options) {
    await checkCredentials(options.sender, options.networkId, options.keyStore);
    console.log(`Sending ${options.amount} NEAR to ${options.receiver} from ${options.sender}`);
    const near = await connect(options);
    const account = await near.account(options.sender);
    const result = await account.sendMoney(options.receiver, utils.format.parseNearAmount(options.amount));
    inspectResponse.prettyPrintResponse(result, options);
};
```

Essentially it connects to the network, creates an account object, and then calls the `sendMoney` method for that account object which is through `near-api-js`. The way it's instantiated is through `near.account()` which behind the scenes does the following (found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/near-api-js/src/near.ts#L108-L111)):

```js
    async account(accountId: string): Promise<Account> {
        const account = new Account(this.connection, accountId);
        return account;
    }
```

This is just calling the class' constructor passing in the connection and account ID. Up until this point, we have no reference to the private or public key other than the connection which has a keystore indicating WHERE the keypair will be found. Ok moving on.

After the account class is initialized, the `sendMoney` method is called and the only action is a simple transfer with the amount. The code for this method can be seen [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/near-api-js/src/account.ts#L325-L330).

```js
    async sendMoney(receiverId: string, amount: BN): Promise<FinalExecutionOutcome> {
        return this.signAndSendTransaction({
            receiverId,
            actions: [transfer(amount)]
        });
    }
```

You'll notice that it calls the `signAndSendTransaction` method that is part of the Account Class (found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/near-api-js/src/account.ts#L200-L244)).

```js
async signAndSendTransaction({ receiverId, actions, returnError }: SignAndSendTransactionOptions): Promise<FinalExecutionOutcome> {
        let txHash, signedTx;
        // TODO: TX_NONCE (different constants for different uses of exponentialBackoff?)
        const result = await exponentialBackoff(TX_NONCE_RETRY_WAIT, TX_NONCE_RETRY_NUMBER, TX_NONCE_RETRY_WAIT_BACKOFF, async () => {
            [txHash, signedTx] = await this.signTransaction(receiverId, actions);
            const publicKey = signedTx.transaction.publicKey;

            try {
                return await this.connection.provider.sendTransaction(signedTx);
            } 
...
...
```

Out of this method, the important thing is `this.signTransaction` whose method is found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/near-api-js/src/account.ts#L180-L194):

```js
    protected async signTransaction(receiverId: string, actions: Action[]): Promise<[Uint8Array, SignedTransaction]> {
        const accessKeyInfo = await this.findAccessKey(receiverId, actions);
        if (!accessKeyInfo) {
            throw new TypedError(`Can not sign transactions for account ${this.accountId} on network ${this.connection.networkId}, no matching key pair exists for this account`, 'KeyNotFound');
        }
        const { accessKey } = accessKeyInfo;

        const block = await this.connection.provider.block({ finality: 'final' });
        const blockHash = block.header.hash;

        const nonce = accessKey.nonce.add(new BN(1));
        return await signTransaction(
            receiverId, nonce, actions, baseDecode(blockHash), this.connection.signer, this.accountId, this.connection.networkId
        );
    }
```

In this method, there's a sneaky `this.findAccessKey` being done whose code can be found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/near-api-js/src/account.ts#L259-L301).

```js
    async findAccessKey(receiverId: string, actions: Action[]): Promise<{ publicKey: PublicKey; accessKey: AccessKeyView }> {
        // TODO: Find matching access key based on transaction (i.e. receiverId and actions)
        const publicKey = await this.connection.signer.getPublicKey(this.accountId, this.connection.networkId);
        if (!publicKey) {
            throw new TypedError(`no matching key pair found in ${this.connection.signer}`, 'PublicKeyNotFound');
        }

        const cachedAccessKey = this.accessKeyByPublicKeyCache[publicKey.toString()];
        if (cachedAccessKey !== undefined) {
            return { publicKey, accessKey: cachedAccessKey };
        }

        try {
            const rawAccessKey = await this.connection.provider.query<AccessKeyViewRaw>({
                request_type: 'view_access_key',
                account_id: this.accountId,
                public_key: publicKey.toString(),
                finality: 'optimistic'
            });

            // store nonce as BN to preserve precision on big number
            const accessKey = {
                ...rawAccessKey,
                nonce: new BN(rawAccessKey.nonce),
            };
            // this function can be called multiple times and retrieve the same access key
            // this checks to see if the access key was already retrieved and cached while
            // the above network call was in flight. To keep nonce values in line, we return
            // the cached access key.
            if (this.accessKeyByPublicKeyCache[publicKey.toString()]) {
                return { publicKey, accessKey: this.accessKeyByPublicKeyCache[publicKey.toString()] };
            }

            this.accessKeyByPublicKeyCache[publicKey.toString()] = accessKey;
            return { publicKey, accessKey };
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.type == 'AccessKeyDoesNotExist') {
                return null;
            }

            throw e;
        }
    }
```

If you take a look at this code, you'll notice a really important line:

```js
const publicKey = await this.connection.signer.getPublicKey(this.accountId, this.connection.networkId);
```

What is this returning? The short answer is that if you're using the NEAR-CLI, the `connection.signer` comes from `UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore` since your keys are stored in `.near-credentials`. Now let's look at this `getPublicKey` method found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/abb2d195a31fa5899c0fd90165f21017695c88bc/packages/near-api-js/src/signer.ts#L76-L82):

```js
    async getPublicKey(accountId?: string, networkId?: string): Promise<PublicKey> {
        const keyPair = await this.keyStore.getKey(networkId, accountId);
        if (keyPair === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return keyPair.getPublicKey();
    }
```

It does `this.keyStore.getKey` where the `keyStore` is the `UnencryptedFileSystemKeyStore` I mentioned earlier. The `getKey` method is then found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/abb2d195a31fa5899c0fd90165f21017695c88bc/packages/near-api-js/src/key_stores/unencrypted_file_system_keystore.ts#L111-L118):

```js
    async getKey(networkId: string, accountId: string): Promise<KeyPair> {
        // Find key / account id.
        if (!await exists(this.getKeyFilePath(networkId, accountId))) {
            return null;
        }
        const accountKeyPair = await readKeyFile(this.getKeyFilePath(networkId, accountId));
        return accountKeyPair[1];
    }
```

In this function, the final culprit is the `readKeyFile` where it returns the key pair (both public and private). This can be found [here](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/abb2d195a31fa5899c0fd90165f21017695c88bc/packages/near-api-js/src/key_stores/unencrypted_file_system_keystore.ts#L48-L56):

```js
export async function readKeyFile(filename: string): Promise<[string, KeyPair]> {
    const accountInfo = await loadJsonFile(filename);
    // The private key might be in private_key or secret_key field.
    let privateKey = accountInfo.private_key;
    if (!privateKey && accountInfo.secret_key) {
        privateKey = accountInfo.secret_key;
    }
    return [accountInfo.account_id, KeyPair.fromString(privateKey)];
}
```

Notice that it returns a KeyPair that is generated **from the private key**. This means that no matter what the public key is, it will overwrite it. I did a quick test where I console logged the `accountInfo` and it indeed returned the incorrect public key that I had set manually but when it generates the KeyPair from the private key, that information is overwritten.

TLDR:
When the your account signs a transaction, the public key is re-generated based on the private key. It doesn't matter what public key you have in your `.near-credentials` since it is overwritten when the KeyPair is created based on the private key.

Comment: You went spelunking in the code to a degree I certainly wasn't expecting. Thanks!

Comment: So, not sure I'm fully in deep but... as long as there is any full access public key on the account which links back to the private key in the `.near-credentials` file, the blockchain will accept the signed transaction from that private key?  I'm trying to make sure this doesn't have implications where a private key can exceed the access rights of its corresponding public key(s).

Comment: @ErikTrautman If there is a full access public key on the account linking back to the private key (we don't care about public key) in `.near-credentials`, the chain will accept the signed transaction, yes. This is also the case for limited access keys which are in `.near-credentials` but instead of them being able to sign anything, they can only perform certain actions and are gated to the receiver contract and methods specified when the key was created.